# How to use ffmpeg to make a video from one still image with height from 0 to 100% animation，

Tags: animation, video, ffmpeg, imagemagick, transition

I want use a still image  to make a transparent webm video, this video needs to have the following style:

1. The image height auto increase from 0 to 100% in specific time.
2. I don't want  scroll effect , what i want is just like the image spread from top to bottom

Below is my demo image:

[image: below is my demo image]

This is the effect I want:

[image: this is the effect i want]

Black color part represent transparency.

Comment: *"I want use a still image to make a transparent webm video"* Is the black color supposed to represent transparency? The wipe effect is easy, and I could answer that now. But transparency seems to be a requirement for you. It is not clear how transparency is involved.

Comment: Black color part represent transparency. 
I know how transparency how to involved, please tell me how to code the wipe effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: wipedown transition]
<sub>1 second transition example</sub>

`ffmpeg` command for 5 second transition:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i input.png -filter_complex "drawbox=thickness=fill:color=black[black];[black][0]xfade=transition=wipedown:duration=5" output.webm
```

- `-loop 1` loops image.
- `-t 5` sets image duration to 5 seconds.
- `drawbox=thickness=fill:color=black` [drawbox filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) to make black video from input.
- `xfade=transition=wipedown:duration=5` [xfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade) filter using *wipedown* transition with a duration of 5 seconds.

Also see:

- [FFmpeg Wiki: xfade transitions gallery](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: VP9 WebM Encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9)

Comment: Is there a way to make the black box part to be transparent?
I used ：ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.png -filter_complex "drawbox=thickness=fill:color=black[black];[black][0]xfade=transition=wipedown:duration=5" output.webm  ,but it not work

Comment: first  i try: 
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i input.png -filter_complex "drawbox=thickness=fill:color=black[black];[black][0]xfade=transition=wipedown:duration=5" -c:v libvpx-vp9  output.webm

Comment: then 
ffmpeg -i bg.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i output.webm -filter_complex overlay -shortest -y -t 5 all.mp4

Comment: but the effect will like this

Comment: https://fun-1305585395.cos.ap-guangzhou.myqcloud.com/chen/2021-08-30-all.mp4

Comment: all the text will appear at the begin of the video , I want it 0 to 100% but not the effect like the link I give before

Comment: ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i bg.png -t 5 -loop 1 -i input.png -filter_complex "[0]format=rgb24,drawbox=thickness=fill,split[black][black2];[black2]negate[white];[black][white]xfade=transition=wipedown:duration=1:offset=0[alf];[0][1]overlay=format=auto[ovr];[ovr][alf]alphamerge[fg];[0][fg]overlay=format=auto,format=yuv420p" output.mp4

Comment: @XiangChen You asked how to do something, I gave answer, then you changed requirements and asked for more. That's not how Stack Overflow works. See the [tour].